# File saved in downloads but does not appear in Download app

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file, android-download-manager, android-mediascanner

I am saving an image in download but when i open the download apps i don't the see the file. I tried using MediaScannerConnection to scan but still it does not appear.here is my code. please help

```
 private void createPNGFile()
    {
        File downloadPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File createPNGImage = new File(downloadPath.getAbsolutePath(),"image.png");

        try {
            InputStream is;
            is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.icon);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(createPNGImage);
            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(data);

            os.write(data);
            is.close();
            os.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Created (Path): " + createPNGImage.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            scanFiles(createPNGImage);
}catch(IOException e)
{
}

}

private void scanFiles(final File fileObj)
{
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{

                        fileObj.getAbsolutePath()},

                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)

                    {

                        Log.d("Media Scan", "Scan Completed" + fileObj.getAbsolutePath());
                    }

                });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code after saving image:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(createPNGImage);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Comment: well i have tried that ..its not working as well...I have used this code with hardcoded values..now i can see the file,,but unable to open it ..i am confused what exactly mediascanner is about?
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.addCompletedDownload("Image","Image Saved",true,"image.png",fileObj.getAbsolutePath(),1,true);